# Redirecting from one Action filter attribute from another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I have two action filter attributes in my MVC app, where I am doing some work in OnActionExecuting event. And depending on a certain condition in first one, I need to execute the same block of code as the second one. So I was thinking to reuse the code.

My first question, Can I do that? then How.

Second, Is that a good approach?

UPDATE:

```
public class Primary : ActionFilterAttribute{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
      if(there is no cookie){
          // Code
      }
      else{
          // Execute the same code block as Secondary OnActionExecuting
      }
   }
}

public class Secondary : ActionFilterAttribute{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
       // Access cookie and do other work
   }
}

[Primary]
public ActionResult MyPrimaryAction(Guid id){
    // Do work
}

[Secondary]
public ActionResult MySecondaryAction(Guid id){
    // Do work
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a code sample of what have you done ? Because it's unclear.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for replying. Updated with a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a base class :

```
public class BaseCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
       // Access cookie and do other work
   }
}
```

Then update you two attribute classes :

```
public class Primary : BaseCookieAttribute {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
      if(there is no cookie){
          // Code
      }
      else{
          base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
   }
}
```

Then you don't need your secondary attribute because you can use directly `BaseCookieAttribute` on your action method.